# Approximating $ | \ln(x)| $ by $-\ln(x)$ near 0

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, approximation

I am reading a text on the dominated convergence theorem. As I am going through the examples, I can see that some of them use the fact that, when $x$ is close to $0$: $$ |\ln(x)| \approx -\ln(x) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,[x \approx 0]$$ I won't quite see where this come from. A am familiar with the usual Taylor developments such as those of $\ln(1-x)$ but still, I don't see if it's of any help to understand the above approximation. Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, for $x\in (0,1], |\ln(x)|=-\ln(x)$.

Comment: Exactly. So you believe that the $\approx$ sign is a typo? I would also think so. The reason why I was puzzled is that the author was fairly picky on the details and everything in the text was correct so far.

Comment: Might very well be then. You would have to further check the context but it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that by definition

- $|x|=x\quad$ for $x\ge 0$
- $|x|=-x\,$ for $x< 0$

and then, since $\ln x <0$ for $0<x<1$, we have that $$|\ln x|=-\ln x=\ln \frac1x$$

Answer (score 0):

The "$\approx$" should rather be a "$=$", because they are exactly the same quantity for all $x\in (0,1)$.